# Uninstalling ClickOnce application does not allow me to re-install from different location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I am new to ClickOnce applications.  I published my application (locally, on my dev computer), installed the application using the setup.exe inside the published folder, and then ran the program.  Everything was good.

I made some updates to the application, and wanted to install the new version on my computer to test it.  So I uninstalled the previous version, using Add/Remove Programs.  Now when I go to install the next version (from a different directory than the first install), I get the infamous "You cannot start application from this location because it is already installed from a different location." message.

I am looking into using the install-over-the-interwebs option, so that I can just update it online, for my client, but for now, I was just testing using the "From CD-ROM" install.

Basically, I'm hosed.  My previous install is uninstalled, so I can't access that.  And any new version cannot be installed because the installed is complaining that my previous one is still there.

My goal is to convince the computer that my previous version was indeed uninstalled.  Apparently there is something lingering that is confusing it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for me was a 2-part fix.

First, I now update my app from a URL.  You can use a local folder, or a website for this.  The way I did it was publish my app into a folder of a website within the same solution.  Then I publish the website to an azure site.  Then to download the app I just go to that website/.

Second, I followed some advice found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9e4b714e-bad4-4c62-a7ad-3c80e32d95eb/clickonce-fails-with-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range?forum=winformssetup
The advice was to do this:

```
Mike, I am one of the previous posters here. I "solved" this (i.e. it rarely happens anymore) by turning off ClickOnce automatic version incrementing, and by making sure at every release I change the version in four places:
- assembly info for both assembly and file version
- ClickOnce version (making sure to keep the automatically increase version checkbox off)
- under Update, making sure I always set the minimum version to the same as elsewhere
```

I found that my version numbers didn't match in all these places -- specifically the assembly number and file version number weren't being updated inside the AssemblyInfo.cs.  Once I had manually set those all to the same new number, published the app to my local folder (inside the website), published my website to azure, gone into my website via FTP and deleted old version folders in the "Application Files" folder, and downloaded the app from my website as described above, I could install and run the app without errors.

I don't know if this fix solves anyone else's problem(s) along the way, but there it is, for what it's worth.

This answer also is very helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/365f8c65-b413-428e-af93-f150059a185f/cannot-runinstalluninstall-a-clickonce-application?forum=winformssetup

Thanks for reading.